# EF Core 2+ - Eager loading using generic repository

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.2

My `BaseRespository` is like so:

```
public abstract class BaseRespository<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected BaseRespository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }      
}
```

And I access the `GetByCondition` method like so:

```
public async Task<Tips> GetTipBySlug(string slug)
{
    Expression<Func<Tips, bool>> predicate = (t) => t.Slug == slug &&
                                                    t.Status == (int)LU_Status.active &&
                                                    t.User.Status == (int)LU_Status.active;

    return await _tipRepository.GetByCondition(predicate);
}
```

I want to use the `Include` and `ThenInclude` of EF Core with the predicate(This is just my desire) like so:

```
public async Task<Tips> GetTipBySlug(string slug)
        {
            Expression<Func<Tips, bool>> whereExpr = (t) => t.Include(t=>t.User).ThenInclude(u=>u.UserImages)
                                                            t.Slug == slug &&
                                                            t.Status == (int)LU_Status.active &&
                                                            t.User.Status == (int)LU_Status.active;

            return await _tipRepository.GetByCondition(whereExpr);
        }
```

How can I add the desired `t.Include(t=>t.User).ThenInclude(u=>u.UserImages)` to the predicate using EF CORE 2 and above?

Comment: A predicate is function that returns a boolean. It shouldn't be abused by somehow adding  includes to it (separation of concerns). Add `Includes` as arguments to the Get method. That is, if you insist on using the repository pattern.

Comment: @GertArnold I have already read some of your answers when I was searching an answer before, it seems like you don't like this pattern.
I read some of the solutions for an old questions, I was just wondering if there was something out of the box for EF Core.

Comment: Don't like... well, it's just that there's often no reason to add this redundant layer to your code. That's a dry fact, not a matter of opinion. If you have good reasons, go for it. But there's no way to combine a predicate and `Include`s. For one, a predicate is the input of a `Where` clause. An `Include` is a different thing altogether.

Comment: So I need a second parameter for the path.

Comment: Yep, that's what all repo builders do.

Comment: The essential part of the post marked as duplicate is the `include` parameter of the [GetFirstOrDefaultAsync](https://github.com/Arch/UnitOfWork/blob/master/src/UnitOfWork/Repository.cs#L379) method in [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoreunitofwork) pacjkage which is extended variant of your `GetByCondition` method.

Comment: @IvanStoev thx, I missed that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this worked without the need to split up your logic across multiple repository argumets, would you really prefer to write

```
        Expression<Func<Tips, bool>> whereExpr = (t) => t.Include(t=>t.User).ThenInclude(u=>u.UserImages)
                                                        t.Slug == slug &&
                                                        t.Status == (int)LU_Status.active &&
                                                        t.User.Status == (int)LU_Status.active;

        return await _tipRepository.GetByCondition(whereExpr);
```

over the way EF was designed to be used:

```
    var q = _tipRepository.Set<Tips>() 
                          .Include(t=>t.User)
                          .ThenInclude(u=>u.UserImages)
                          .Where(t => t.Status == (int)LU_Status.active)
                          .Where(t => t.User.Status == (int)LU_Status.active);

    return await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Why would you want to create an `Expression<Func<Tips,bool>>` instead of just an `IQueryabe<T>`.  It has *nothing* do do with whether the repository is "generic", and *everything* to do with how you want to write queries.  Queries are written by the *consumers* of the repository.  Not by or in the repository (except to the extent you want to reuse a query across consumers).

The crazy thing about this design is that it allows the repo's consumer to specify the query.  It just forces them to do it through a clunky, bespoke API.

You could write it like this:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetByCondition<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> baseQuery = null) where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> q = Set<TEntity>();
    if (baseQuery != null)
    {
       q = baseQuery(Set<TEntity>());
    }
    return await q.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

You don't need Expression for that one because the `Include` is not deferred.  It's a function that returns an IIncludableQueryable, so it's a query transformation function.

And then:

```
public async Task<Tips> GetTipBySlug(string slug)
{
    Expression<Func<Tips, bool>> whereExpr = (t) => t.Slug == slug &&
                                                    t.Status ==1 &&
                                                    t.User.Status == 1;

    return await GetByCondition(whereExpr, s => s.Include(t => t.User).ThenInclude(u => u.UserImages))                                                           ;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to write the same query multiple times if the only difference between them is the `ThenInclude` part, the predicate is the same so why should I write many queries?

By sending 2 arguments to the `generic` repository it suppose to make life easier... 

The main point in the question is how to send the second argument? I couldn't find a recent answer for that(Including the `ThenInclude` part)

Comment: If you're repeating the "active=1" boilerplate, why not use a Global Query Filter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: That's a nice feature, is it possible to send as argument the `ThenInclude` Part to the repository, all the answers I saw had only the `Include` part?

Comment: See updated answer, but I don't see how that's going to make anyone's life easier.

Comment: Thank you David, I will try this tomorrow, why not? This way I have 1 method in my generic repository `GetByCondition` and I can send it the predicate and the tables as arguments instead of writing 2 methods that will be different only by the included tables.

Comment: Because you don't need either method in your repository.  You end up having to alter your repository for each controller or use case.  Just let the calling code decide what objects they need, how the graphs are shaped, whether they are change-tracking or not, etc.

Comment: Thx, I tried working without repository, it lead to too many custom functions I had to write, I prefer it this way , Controller -> BLL -> DAL -> BLL ->DTO->ViewModel-> View

Comment: Hi David, can you look at this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698796/ef-core-2-2-cannot-project-while-using-iqueryable